# Python return statement wont work?

Tags: function, python-3.x, syntax-error, return

def savings (pocket_money, paper_route, spending):

--- return pocket_money + paper_route - spending

print (savings (10, 10, 5))

This code says that there is a syntax error where print is. Idk whats wrong, i got that code from a beginner to python book. I tried several more examples from the book that involve the return statement, and all gave me a syntax error where print is. One thing I noticed was that when I press ENTER on the return statement the cursor appears with no spaces, as in ending the block. Idk if this is normal; I just started learning python a few days ago.

I am using Python 3.4.1

Assuming the coordinate transformations that I posted previously, would I then have to split up the integral into two parts like the following \int_0^$u_2$(\frac{$v_3$-$v_2$}{$u_3$-$u_2$})$u^2$du + \int_$u_2$^$u_3$[(\frac{$v_3$-$v_2$}{$u_3$-$u_2$})u + $v_3$ -(\frac{$v_3$-$v_2$}{$u_3$-$u_2$})$u_3$]u du ?

Comment: can you paste the error trace?

Comment: To use a code block on stack overflow, add 4 spaces in front of each line of code. To put some words into a code block, surround with backticks: *`*

Comment: def savings(pocket_money, paper_route, spending):
                                                                 `return pocket_money + paper_route - spending`
                                                    print(savings(10, 10, 5))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I get

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.3
$ python
>>> def s(pm,pr,s):
...    return pm+pr-s
...
>>> print s(10,10,5)
15
>>> def s(pm,pr,s):
...    return pm+pr-s
... print s(10,10,5)
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    print s(10,10,5)
        ^
```

are you sure you are putting the blank line after defining your function?

Comment: That's what it was. I wasn't putting the blank line after defining the function lol Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I put this into my interpreter and it worked fine:

```
>>> def savings (pocket_money, paper_route, spending):                                                                                                                                                
...     return pocket_money + paper_route - spending                                                                                                                                            
... 
>>> print (savings (10, 10, 5))
15
```

Tested using python 3.3.5 and python 3.4.0

Is there another interpreter you can use? Are your parameters all numbers?
Do **NOT** use tabs.

Comment: I I'm not really sure what an interpreter is, and yah my parameters is made up of all numbers. Not even the simplest lines of code involving the return statement are working for me. It's driving me crazy, cause idk whats wrong lol

Comment: Check this link out: https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode

You need to add 4 spaces after every method header / loop / if statement. (anything after the colon generally)

In my example, see the `...    return pocket_money + paper_route - spending` line. The 4 spaces after the elipses (...) but before the return statement is the indent to show that the return is based in the savings method. Python works on indented lines **instead** of semi colons and brackets.